# make: gcc: Command not found with include in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to a create a makefile architecture so I have one global makefile at the top which call another in a subdirectory.

Global makefile :

```
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -W -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS     =

PROJECT     = proj

SOURCES     =

PATH        = $(PROJECT)
include $(PATH)/Makefile

all : $(PROJECT).exe

$(PROJECT).exe :
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $(SOURCES) -o $@

clean :
  rm -rf *.exe
```

Subdirectory makefile :

```
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -W -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS     = 

SOURCES     += $(PATH)/main.c
```

When I "make" in the top directory I have the following error :

```
gcc -W -Wall -pedantic     proj/main.c -o proj.exe
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:17: FK16_jake.exe] Error 127
```

But when i type exactly the same command (gcc -W -Wall -pedantic     proj/main.c -o proj.exe) in my terminal, it's building.

And if I remove the makefile include, he recognize gcc but don't build because no sources (normal behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UNIX shell, the [environment variable `PATH`](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) specifies the set of directories to search for executables when you run a command.

The [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html) says:

> When `make` runs a recipe, variables defined in the makefile are
>   placed into the environment of each shell.  This allows you to pass
>   values to sub-`make` invocations (see [Recursive Use of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html)).  By default, only variables that came from the environment
>   or the command line are passed to recursive invocations.

Because `PATH` is a shell variable and is defined in the environment of `make`, it is "came from the environment". That means when you modify the value with `PATH  = $(PROJECT)` the updated value will be set in the environment of the shell that runs the recipe for `$(PROJECT).exe`. That means the shell runs with a bad value for the `PATH` and so cannot find `gcc`.

To avoid this confusion, do not use `PATH` as a makefile variable. Use another name which is not the same as an environment variable that the shell depends on. You could call it `PROJECT_PATH` instead, or just use `$(PROJECT)` instead of `$(PATH)`.

Answer (score 5):

You are overriding PATH, which is used to determine where to look for executables. Change this variable and it should work.